# How can i fix my laggy textinput in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using the EXPO App to test my react-native project. When I type things in the TextInput the app begins to lag. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

```
            <View style={styles.logincontainercontainer}>
                <View style={styles.logincontainer}>
                    <Icon name="email" size={25} color={COLORS.grey} />
                    <TextInput  
                        style={{paddingLeft:3, flex:1}}
                        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.grey} placeholder="Email"
                        value={email}
                        blurOnSubmit={false}
                        onSubmitEditing={() => secondTextInput.focus() }
                        onChangeText={text=> setemail(text)}
                    />
                </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have a `useEffect()` that have a dependency on your text. But if this keeps persisting, I recommend you to use debounce function to wrap the `setemail` function.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

const processEmailChange = debounce((t) => setemail(t));
```

And use `processEmailChange` inside `onChangeText` like `onChangeText={(text)=>processEmailChange(text)}`

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if it re-renders a lot for each key stroke by adding a console log in your use effect.
Then,Try removing all the console logs in the component and this email dependency from the dependency array of useEffect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).